# How to open my NAT type on PC?

Tags: router, nat

As a gamer it is really frustrating to have a NAT type that's "strict", as it makes it really hard to find games/matches with other people online. After some research I came across something called "DMZ" and turned it on my router settings, I went to windows command prompt and typed ipconfig. I used the IPV4 and set that as DMZ and then of course in my network settings I also used the same IP address I got through the ipconfig command (and used google DNS). This worked, for a few months that is, and now my NAT type is strict despite having DMZ enabled and despite making sure I've done the entire process correctly.

I called my ISP and they had no idea about what NAT is, except they mentioned that for an extra cost they could get me a "static ip address", now I am completely baffled. Is a static ip from my ISP is what I need? Or is there another way.

I am looking forward to answer, that also explains the situation so that I also learn something in the process of find a resolution.

[image]

Comment: You should write to developers of your favorite games instead. Because with carrier-grade NAT, this cannot be changed. New games must not rely on a particular NAT type.

Comment: Change your ISP. Any other ISP employing helpdesk that dont know what NAT is is not a serious player.  A static IP address wont fix your problem - although you should check if your ISP is using CGN (carrier grade NAT) - if they are then that is the problem - and a static IO will fix it - because its bypassing CGN.  If you provide the output of a traceroute to Google or similar we should be able to advise if your isp is using CGN.

Comment: You sure your computer wasn't assigned a different ip through DHCP? If it was, you need to update the DMZ address in the routers config.

Comment: @davidgo I have now updated the question with the traceroute to google.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart If I go to cmd and I type ipconfig my IPV4 is the same as what I have assigned to the DMZ, and the same is what I have assigned for my IPV4 ethernet settings on Windows.

Comment: @davidgo Unfortunately changing my ISP isn't an option, cause they are the only service provider in my region.

Comment: I cant be 100% sure, but it looks a lot like you are behind double NAT. (I'd say Carrier Grade NAT, but they are not using a range set aside for end user NAT, not CGN - thr second hop is 172.25.x.x ).  Assuming this to be the case you need to get a "public IP" from your provider or use a VPN which provides a static IP

Comment: @davidgo could you tell me what  a "public ip" is? and is it the same as a "static ip"?

Comment: A public IP address is any "normal" address which is directly routable on the Internet. A static IP addres is an address which dies not change. Typically, when an ISP offers a static IP address it is also a public IP address (but it is possible to have a static IP that is not a public IP - eg on a LAN)...

Comment: Another practical (but maybe imperfect) way of looking at a Public IP address is any IP address not in a range set aside for local use, or where the same address might exist on multiple LANS. The ranges set aside as not public IPs are typically in the following ranges -192.168.*.*  10.*.*.* 172.16-31.*.*  127.*.*.*  100.64-127.*.*

Comment: @davidgo assuming your evaluation is on point(I understand you can't be 100% sure), a static IP will resolve my issue. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes.Thats  right.

Comment: I haven't fully tested these instructions but they seem fairly simple.  How to Tell If Your ISP Uses Carrier Grade NAT (CG-NAT) https://winbuzzer.com/2020/05/29/windows-10-how-to-tell-if-your-isp-uses-carrier-grade-nat-cg-nat-xcxwbt/

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic IP vs static IP is not relevant to NAT. But if ISP is using CGN (carrier grade NAT)then static IP can help. Do you use VPN as well?
If the gateway has a DMZ, it will basically give the router a direct connection to the internet, bypassing the gateway’s NAT,firewall, and DHCP so that your networked devices get those values directly from your router.

If this is not the case then no need to change dynamic to static IP in your router settings but it is critical to use IP address allocation for your gaming console.
In the Router select LAN Settings” or something similar, select “Address Reservation”, “DHCP Reservation'' and select the IP address of your gaming console.

If you use Windows do not forget to have the Turn on network discovery in advanced sharing options enabled and use in IPv4 the same IP, subnet mask and default gateway
as showed on ipconfig results on your PC and avoid any IP address conflict.

Instead of DMZ try to only Forward specific ports to the PS4 console. DMZ is the last resort since it leaves your system utterly open to security threats.

Many routers have UPnP enabled, if this is not your case, you have to open specific ports, firewall configuration set up for correct ports and transport protocol (TCP/UDP).

From the Traceroute you added up you can check the route that your computer uses to connect to a remote server.

You hit timeouts after 142.250.225.249 and no hops and respond afterwards,
the last router with this IP has a valid return path to the server that issued the traceroute if nothing is blocking the packets.

Generally when you see request time outs in the either the nodes are too busy to process your request. The target server does not exist on the network, which means it is either disconnected or turned off.
Also it could be that the nodes are configured to deny trace requests.

There are devices that only allow ICMP packets but deny traceroute packets. To get around this, add an -I flag to the traceroute syntax so that it uses ICMP packets instead. But I assume you can use VPN that can be causing as well TTL 0 and the packets are discarded, and never reach the host.

Comment: supposing he is under Carrier grade NAT, you haven't given him a solution there